# Find versions of libraries pulled into project via CMakeLists

Tags: c++, cmake

In my project, configured by CMake, I use several external libraries (here "A") (which again are linked to other libraries (here "B")). Now, after upgrading those secondary external libraries ("B"), sometimes I forget to upgrade the initial external libraries ("A"). This leads to errors/warnings during the configuration stage of the main project, such as

```
CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:416 (add_executable):
  Cannot generate a safe runtime search path for target TTM-equation because
  files in some directories may conflict with libraries in implicit
  directories:

    runtime library [libmkl_gnu_thread.so] in /opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64 may be hidden by files in:
      /opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2019.0.117/linux/mkl/lib/intel64
    runtime library [libmkl_intel_lp64.so] in /opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64 may be hidden by files in:
      /opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2019.0.117/linux/mkl/lib/intel64
    runtime library [libmkl_core.so] in /opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64 may be hidden by files in:
      /opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2019.0.117/linux/mkl/lib/intel64
    runtime library [libmkl_intel_thread.so] in /opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64 may be hidden by files in:
      /opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2019.0.117/linux/mkl/lib/intel64

  Some of these libraries may not be found correctly.
```

Here I have two different versions of the intel MKL libraries as secondary library, which are pulled in by different initial external libraries, and which collide.
In order to find the culprit for pulling in the "old" version of the MKL libraries, I usually have to go through all the linked libraries with `ldd`, and check which of them is pulling in which version of the MKL libraries. This works fine for only a few external libraries, but as soon as I have >5 external libraries, it gets annoying and time-consuming.
Thus, is there an easier way of detecting the problematic library "A", without having to loop over all the included libraries?

Comment: How do you include those libraries in your CMakeLists.txt?

Comment: Using `find_package()` and (for linking) `target_link_libraries(${TARGET} ${LIBRARY_A1} ${LIBRARY_A2})` etc.

Comment: And you upgrade those libs manually? I don't want to state the obvious, but a package manager would manage dependencies (and their upgrades) automatically. You probably can't use one for some reason.

Comment: Some libraries are in active development (thus difficult to rely on the package manager), others are not available via it. If available, I try to use all packages from the package manager

Comment: You might want to add that information to your question, that using a pacman is out of the question. The only other idea I have is integrating the libraries via git submodule and automate building them in your project's CMake.